# Tile Map Javascript won't draw

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>TileMap</title>
  <style>
    #canvas {
      outline: 1px solid #000;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="canvas" height="1000" width="1000"></canvas>
  <script>
    var canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    var grass = new Image();
    var water = new Image();
    var dirt = new Image();


    grass.src = 'grass1.jpg';
    water.src = 'water.jpg';
    dirt.src = 'dirt.jpg';

    var xpos = 0;
    var ypos = 0;

    var map = [
      [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 1, 0]

    ];

    for (var i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < map[i].length; j++) {

        if (map[i][j] == 0) {
          context.drawImage(grass1, xpos, ypos);
        }

        if (map[i][j] == 1) {
          context.drawImage(dirt, xpos, ypos);
        }

        if (map[i][j] == 2) {
          context.drawImage(water, xpos, ypos);
        }

        xpos += 100;
      }
      xpos = 0;
      ypos += 100;

    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I think my problem is with the image dimensions which are all 100 X 100.

I want to make this tile map solely in javascrtipt,html and css without using any jquery.

Please Help, this is my first  javascript project.

Comment: I'm getting a `ReferenceError: grass1 is not defined` in the console. Looks like it should say `grass` here instead: `context.drawImage(grass1, xpos, ypos);`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to draw the Canvas before the images are actually loaded. Therefore, write the drawing part in a function and call the function, once images are loaded. For example...

```js
grass.onload = function () {
          fill_canvas(grass);       // FILL THE CANVAS WITH THE IMAGE.
      }

function fill_canvas(img) {

    ... write your canvas context here.

}
```

Pass multiple image references to the fill_canvas() function. Its explained [here](http://www.encodedna.com/html5/canvas/add-image-to-html5-canvas-using-javascript.htm).

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer!!!!! could you please type the code needed to pass the multiple image references to the fill_canvas() function?

Comment: window.onload=function(){
var xpos=0;
var ypos=0;
var grass = new Image();
var water = new Image();
var dirt  = new Image();
grass.src = 'grass1.jpg';
water.src = 'water.jpg';
dirt.src = 'dirt.jpg';
grass.onload=function(){
 fill_canvas(grass);
}
water.onload=function(){
 fill_canvas(water);
}
dirt.onload=function(){
 fill_canvas(dirt);
}
function fill_canvas(dirt,water,grass) {
            // CREATE CANVAS CONTEXT.
            var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
            var context = canvas.getContext('2d')
      
}
}

Comment: @NickGreen That’s how you will pass the parameters. However, in this context it is not necessary, as you have declared all the images outside the function.

Comment: But it won't work... could you  please write the full code?                                 Thanks for the support!